# Directory of Vectorization Report for Intel C++ Compiler in VS 10

Tags: c++, intel, vectorization, icc

In VS 10, I set "Vectorizer Diagnostic Level" to "n=2" and "Optimization Diagnostic Phase" to "hpo" as directed in "A Guide to Vectorization with Intel C++ Compilers". However, (this may be a silly question), where is that report? There is neither something to be shown in "output", nor project directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The vectorization diagnostics are usually emitted as part of the normal compiler diagnostic output, e.g.

```
$ icc -Wall -msse3 foo.c -vec-report=2 -o foo

...

foo.c(1337): (col. 5) remark: loop was not vectorized: existence of vector dependence.
foo.c(1337): (col. 5) remark: loop was not vectorized: not inner loop.
foo.c(1337): (col. 5) remark: loop was not vectorized: not inner loop.
foo.c(1337): (col. 5) remark: loop was not vectorized: existence of vector dependence.
foo.c(1337): (col. 5) remark: loop was not vectorized: existence of vector dependence.
foo.c(1337): (col. 5) remark: loop was not vectorized: nonstandard loop is not a vectorization candidate.
foo.c(1337): (col. 5) remark: loop was not vectorized: not inner loop.
foo.c(1337): (col. 5) remark: LOOP WAS VECTORIZED.
foo.c(1339): (col. 5) remark: loop was not vectorized: existence of vector dependence.
foo.c(1339): (col. 5) remark: loop was not vectorized: existence of vector dependence.
foo.c(1339): (col. 5) remark: loop was not vectorized: not inner loop.
foo.c(1339): (col. 5) remark: loop was not vectorized: statement cannot be vectorized.
foo.c(1339): (col. 5) remark: loop was not vectorized: not inner loop.

...

$
```

Comment: Is the "normal compiler diagnostic output" same thing as "output" window?

Comment: Yes, the above example is just normal console output - so long as you are not redirecting stdout or stderr and you have `-vec-report=2` or greater than you should see something like this.

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing has shown. BTW, "Emit Diagnostics to File" is set to "No". Also, I did not do anything with stdout and stderr.

Comment: What environment are you using ? Try testing it from the command line as per the above example.

Comment: As far as I understand from the word environment, I tried both debug and release modes. I checked my command line and it includes required commands related with diagnostics.

Comment: Are you doing this from within an IDE, such as Eclipse, Visual Studio, Xcode, or some such ?

Comment: What is the option like vec-report for gcc and clang/llvm?

Comment: I'm using VS 2010 and I can't see the report though I'm using the flags. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in a project I'm writing.
It's a Plug In based on a sample code given in an SDK.

If the compiling / building process is configured for "Debug" mode no optimization will be applied and hence no report is given.

You might have the same problem.

I'm having problems figuring how to switch to "Release Mode" (It's no available in the configuration panel):
[Switching from Debug into Release Mode with VS2010 as IDE and Intel C++ Compiler 13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12571182/switching-from-debug-into-release-mode-with-vs2010-as-ide-and-intel-c-compiler)

Please let us know if it worked for you.