# Switching from Debug into Release Mode with VS2010 as IDE and Intel C++ Compiler 13

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, compiler-construction, icc

I have a code of a Plug In from an SDK.
The code is in Debug Mode.
I use Intel Compiler which only applies optimizations in Release Mode.

Under configuration manager of the project only "Debug" mode is defined.

How could I switch to "Release" mode and enable all Intel Compiler's optimizations?
If I enable them on debug mode nothing is applied (Empty Report).

I couldn't find the trick to do so.

Thank You.

P.S.
I do use the /MT switch yet still.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here is the solution,
First of all using the /MD or /MD, which is trivial.
Then define NDEBUG.
Pay attention to do this in every file in the project.
In my case, some files were set to /MTd which sets the Debug mode.

I used Intel Compiler and this thread might help:
http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/328136

Answer (score 1):

Project configurations are managed by the user, so you can create **Release** configuration by yourself if it's missing. In the insides, they can differ by compiler options and defines, mostly. When I had very slow PC, I sometimes used configuration I've created, obviously named `Debug_Optimized`.

For example, Debug configuration usually has `DEBUG` defined. It makes some lines of code comment out, to speed up the resulting program.

You can usually speed up creation of another configuration by basing it on existing one. Look for all "Perfomance" and "Optimizations" tabs and set them according to your needs. There usually isn't one best configuration (sometimes "optimize for size" is faster than "optimize for speed"). Try these options out.

Comment: Hi, I can (And did) set a new configuration. I started with the given (In the code sample) "Debug" mode. Yet no matter which switch I tried I couldn't make the compiler work in "Not Debug Mode" which cancels any optimization (Though I set the optimizations on). The question is, which settings tells the compiler to work in debug mode and how can I turn them off? Thank You.

Comment: The problem is, I have no experience with Intel compiler together with visual studio. Maybe try adding these options to the latest part, commandline parameters?

Comment: I don't have any problem switching to MS Compiler. Is there any indication I can use in MS Compiler whether the code compiled in Debug or Release mode? Thanks.

Comment: I will say it again : there are no Debug and Release modes. There are compiler options, and common sets of these options are put in the default Debug and Release configurations.

Comment: I meant could I use #IFDEF <something> to know which mode is currently working? I understand what you mean and I tried every option I could think of in the configuration and still it seems to work in "Debug" mode (I mean the compiler add the debug data and turns off any optimization).